# Vba selenium copy element text ,open a new window and paste text in element find box

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, automation, copy

I am trying to copy part of an element text and paste it in another element ,in its search box. The element contains a a policy number that i need to check in another system and it looks like this
60.22.9591 / RANDOM VENDOR NAME​
I need to get the numbers before the "/" and remove the dots before pasting . After that I need to open the system in another window, paste the numbers in a search box, click search.Any help will be appropriated

```
Dim pause1, pause2, url As String
 
 pause1 = "00:00:08"
 
 pause2 = "00:00:30"

 url = "http://abv/"

Dim driver As New WebDriver

Dim rowc, cc, columnC As Integer

Dim tblent As Variant

Dim By As selenium.By

Set By = New selenium.By

driver.Get url

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(pause1)

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[4]/a/span").SendKeys "c"

driver.Get url2

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/l/li[5]/ul/li[4]/a/span").SendKeys "v"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(pause1)

driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/l/li[5]/ul/li[4]/a/box").Click

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(pause1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyText = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[4]/a/span").Text
driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/l/li[5]/ul/li[4]/a/span").SendKeys (MyText)
```